# Typescript - Cannot find name 'fetch' (universal library)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fetch-api, isomorphic-fetch-api

I'm aiming to build a **Typescript** library with AJAX calls (by using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)), that can be used by both **client-side** (Webpack/Browserify) **and** back-end developers (**Node**).

However, I can't seem to get the `fetch` to compile without errors.

---

My first attempt has been with [`isomorphic-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) and [`@types/isomorphic-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/isomorphic-fetch). I'm unsure whether the types are complete, but they didn't bring any global variable *(they should be bringing fetch, shouldn't they?)*.

```
npm i isomorphic-fetch @types/isomorphic-fetch
```

index.ts

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
export function execute() {
  return fetch('...') ...
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017"]
}
```

Output:

```
node_modules/@types/isomorphic-fetch/index.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'fetch'.
src/index.ts(4,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'fetch'.
```

**Do I need "`dom`"?** Apparently, with the `dom` lib it does compile and work on both ✓, but I got no control on whether it will actually work on Node. I mean, it will compile whether or not I `import 'isomorphic-fetch'`, but if I miss it in will fail on Node without notice.

Also, Node is not "`dom`", regardless of me wanting to support browsers as well.

---

My second attempt has been with [`whatwg-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/whatwg-fetch).

```
npm i whatwg-fetch @types/whatwg-fetch
```

tsconfig.json

```
"lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017"] // The same.
```

This one doesn't even pass the compilation phase (regardless of the "`dom`" library):

```
> tsc --watch

node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts(11,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'window'.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts(31,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Blob'.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts(31,64): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FormData'.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts(36,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Blob'.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts(37,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FormData'.
17:31:50 - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

With "`dom`":

```
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9353,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Request'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9370,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Request'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9375,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Response'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9386,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Response'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(14940,18): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fetch'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(14945,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'BodyInit'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(14966,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'HeadersInit'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(14976,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15043,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ReferrerPolicy'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15044,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestCache'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15045,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestCredentials'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15046,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestDestination'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15047,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestMode'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15048,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestRedirect'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15049,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestType'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15050,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ResponseType'.
...
```

---

I've also attempted with other similar libraries such as [`fetch-ponyfill`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-ponyfill), but this one doesn't even have types available for TypeScript.

---

How are we supposed to call `fetch` on a universal application (browser + Node)?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you take a look at https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch ?

Comment: @TomaszBubała I did. That's the case #1, but apparently, it doesn't compile without errors without the `dom` library (which I guess it's only meant to be used in browser-only libraries) :/

Comment: It's not a direct answer to what you need, but you may abstract out `fetch` as in clean architecture: https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

Comment: It's 2023 and `isomorphic-fetch` still doesn't work for me unless I add the `dom` library to my tsconfig (which is a no go for server-side). I just don't get it - isn't the point of this to bring `fetch` both server-side and browser-side?

Comment: Definitely skim through https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4948 . Bottom line: It's a mess.

Answer (score 9):

To get proper type definitions you have a couple options.

**If your TypeScript will be running in the browser**:

Add the built-in "DOM" to your compiler libs (either with [the `--lib` command line compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) or to [lib in `tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)). Adding "DOM" to libs is probably the right option if you're TypeScript will be running in a modern browser. However, if you're TypeScript is running in a non-browser environment with a fetch module check Option 2.

**If your TypeScript will be running on the server (node.js)**:

If you're using a library like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) on node, then add the [@types/node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node-fetch) type definitions, and import fetch like `import fetch from "node-fetch"`

**If your TypeScript is running in both browser and server** (e.g. for a server-side rendering project) import the DOM lib and you probably want to add the [isomorphic-fetch package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch).

Answer (score 4):

I had same error using fetch in an angular (typescript) project, I could solve it by declaring fetch like this:

```
  declare var fetch;
```

Comment: `declare const fetch: Function`

Answer (score 2):

If you are transpiling with the below command:

```
"ts-watch": "tsc file1.ts file2.ts --watch"
```

Then remove the individual file declarations and it should work if you have a valid tsconfig.json:

```
"ts-watch": "tsc --watch"
```

Here is an example of a working tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2015",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "ES2015",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types/",
      "index.d.ts"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./typescript/**/*",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing **@types/node** version 20.8.4 or later solves this.

```bash
npm install --save-dev @types/node@">=20.8.4"
```